# Launch an SL4A script from an SL4A script

Tags: android, python, sl4a, start-activity

I would like to start a background SL4A script (on a remote device) from within a different SL4A script. I can launch a script from a terminal by running something like this:

```
$ am start -a \
com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT -n \
com.googlecode.android_scripting/.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher -e \
com.googlecode.android_scripting.extra.SCRIPT_PATH /sdcard/sl4a/scripts/main.py
```

I can't translate this into a `startActivity` call in Python.

The answer to [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737150/launch-android-app-from-sl4a-script) on opening a Twitter client works nicely, but I don't know how to extend that code. For example, how would you add a script path, and where would you put the line `com.googlecode.android_scripting/.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher`?

Comment: Have you checked this link yet?: http://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/run-sl4a-python-script-from-within-android-app/

Comment: I hadn't seen that yet, although some of the code does look familiar - can I import those files "Intent.java" and such into my python scripts, and then do an "Intent i=blah"?

Comment: If you are talking about `IntentBuilders.Java`, SL4A provides you the link to download, all the necessary downloads are provided on that page I gave you.

Comment: The link you sent me talks about writing a java app, and doesn't seem to explain anything related to forming an intent inside sl4a. Sorry, I've read it 4 or 5 times now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18710318/3157779 <to call any app activity and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13780483/3157779 to launch script from another. Languages like python have in built functions to call other scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many, many failed attempts, I now have this working in Ruby - I had an easier time generating the JSON extras this way than in Python.

Important!
  In the command-line version, you call on "com.googlecode.android_scripting/.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher"

From within a script, this is called as "com.googlecode.android_scripting.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher", without the slash. Leaving in the slash crashes sl4a.

[code]

require 'android'
require 'json/pure'

d=Android.new

script = '/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/YOUR_SCRIPT'

data = {"com.googlecode.android_scripting.extra.SCRIPT_PATH"=>script}

extras = JSON.generate(data)

d.startActivity('com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT','','',data,true,'com.googlecode.android_scripting','com.googlecode.android_scripting.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher')

[/code]

I hope this helps!

Comment: The code I posted after the fact is correct, and solved the problem - there is no fail here, except for my lack of familiarity with a language I rarely use.That being said, yone more familiar with Python than I should have no trouble translating the code I posted .

Comment: But it is not an answer to the question, which is how SO works. The question is Python specific and has the Python tag. You should create a new question on how to do it in Ruby and answer your own question there. Other people may have better answers for how to do it in Ruby too.

Answer (score 2):

This function will launch any SL4A script from inside another one.

The first argument should be a path to the script you want to launch. The script can be in any language you have an interpreter installed for.

The second argument is optional and should be a bool. It defaults to `False`. It controls whether the terminal will be visible, so you can see output and errors. It does not effect whether the script has a UI or not.

```
from android import Android
droid = Android()

def launch_script(path, visible=False):

    visibilty   = 'FORE' if visible else 'BACK'
    activity    = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_{0}GROUND_SCRIPT'.format(visibilty)
    extras      = {'com.googlecode.android_scripting.extra.SCRIPT_PATH': path}
    packagename = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting'
    classname   = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher'
    intent      = droid.makeIntent(activity, None, None, extras, None, packagename, classname).result

    droid.startActivityIntent(intent)
```

There's a [gist for this code here](https://gist.github.com/carlsmith/1970be371bae451e868b).

Comment: Broken link. Ba-da-pee-doo.

Comment: I found my original code, so updated the answer to include the code and fixed the link.